# Using ffmpeg in C#. Can't get the FFmpeg output

Tags: c#, winforms, ffmpeg

I'm kind of new to C# and I have tried for a week but can't solve this problem...
I'm creating video information and convert apps by running ffmpeg command and display the output in a TextBox. Here is my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi1 = new ProcessStartInfo("Cmd");
                    psi1.UseShellExecute = false;
                    psi1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    psi1.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    psi1.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    psi1.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    psi1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    var proc = Process.Start(psi1);
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpath.Text))
                    {

                        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd" + " " + txtpath.Text);
                        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"for %a in (*) do ffmpeg -threads 0 -i %a -vf scale=-1:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase %~Na.mp4");
                        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
                    }

                    string s = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                    richTextBox1.Text = s;
```

txtpath.Text is the input folder select by user. After run, the ffmpeg.exe run as background as my wish, but on the text box there is only one line and that's it. I wanna capture the whole process until the end.
And moreover, can i point out which file is running by ffmpeg ?
(Moreoever, the i haved research and find out that ffmpeg process is not the output but the error, that's why i have used StandardError.ReadToEnd )

Comment: Is the output in StandardError? I would expect it to be in StandardOutput. Or is ffmpeg one of those commandline tools that are broken by design?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=progress+ffmpeg+%5Bwinforms%5D

Comment: I have tried StandardOutput before, any get notthing on the text box. After i read this artile : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/492381/StartInfo-RedirectStandardOutp  i tried StandardError and got only the first line :(